# Let $P, Q, R \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be three points not on a line. Prove there is exactly one plane $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ containing $P,Q,R$, namely

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric

Let $P, Q, R \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be three points not on a line. Prove that there is exactly one plane $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ containing $P,Q,R$, namely

$$E = P + \mathbb{R} \cdot (P - Q) + \mathbb{R} \cdot (P - R)$$

---

I know the equation of a plane is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_planes_in_three-dimensional_space

$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$ or written otherwise
$$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0$$

How am I supposed to prove that ? Any hint or help would be welcome, thank you !

Comment: A plane is completely described by three parameters, say $a, b$ and $c$, as if $d\neq 0$ in the equation, then you can divide by $d$ and rename $a'=a/d$ and so on. Try to see how 3 given points not contained in a line could define them.

Comment: For starters, don’t use identical letters for two completely different things. What vector geometry and or linear algebra do you know? We aren’t mind-readers.

Comment: @Dog_69 If the three points are not on a line, we can create two vectors that are linearly independent. If there would be on the same line, then both vectors would be linearly dependent. The two vectors "span" the plane, is that what you mean ?

Comment: To explain @TedShifrin s comment: $x,y,z$ in the equation of the plane are the coordinates of a single point $P=(x,y,z)$. I suggest you rename your points $P,Q,R$ or use numbers to denote the coordinates: $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's written like that in the Wikipedia article with $d = - (ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0)$, I was also confused at first

Comment: @wengen That's one possibility. Given three points, we can form three vectors:$xy,xz,yz$, and one of them is always a linear combination of the other two. If the three points are not in a line, then two of those vectors will be linearly independent, and we're done

Comment: @Dog_69 Ah I see, yes i will do that

Comment: This seems like a homework question. Why are you looking to wikipedia for the definition of a plane? What is the definition in your course?

Comment: Another possibility is to use the 3 points to get 3 equations for $a,b,c$. You should then show that a the points not being colinear is equivalent to the system having one and only one solution. That's the approach I had on mind, but only because you wrote down the equation of the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually just after this section on Wikipedia, there is the same defintion as in the course https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_planes_in_three-dimensional_space#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it $r = r_0 + sv + tw$ I should have included this definition in the post, my bad. It makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal G$ be an affine space, $G$ its associated linear space (over some field $K,$ not necessarily equal to $\Bbb R$), and $P,Q,R\in\mathcal G$ non-[collinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity), i.e. such that the two vectors $P-Q,P-R\in G$ are linearly independent. Then,
$$\mathcal E:=P+K(P-Q)+K(P-R)\subset\mathcal G$$
is an affine plane ([by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4778401/timeline#comment_10156369)) and contains
$$P+0(P-Q)+0(P-R)=P,\quad P+(-1)(P-Q)+0(P-R)=Q,\quad P+0(P-Q)+(-1)(P-R)=R.$$
Conversely, let $\mathcal F\subset\mathcal G$ be an affine plane containing $P,Q,R.$ Then, the associated linear plane $F$ contains $P-Q,P-R$ hence is spanned by them, so that $\mathcal F=P+F=\mathcal E.$

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0):

In the lecture, they gave us this as "proof". I thought maybe someone will find it useful one day, so why not share it.

Claim: If $ P,Q,R \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are three points, which are not on one line, then there exists exactly one Plane $E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, which contains $P,Q,R$, that is $E = P + \mathbb{R} \cdot (P-Q) + \mathbb{R} \cdot (P-R)$

Proof:

Part 1: $E$ contains $P,Q,R$
$$P = P + 0 \cdot (P-Q) + 0 \cdot (P-R)$$
$$Q = P + (-1) \cdot (P-Q) + 0 \cdot (P-R)$$
$$R = P + 0 \cdot (P-Q) + (-1) \cdot (P-R)$$

Part 2: $E$ is a Plane according to Parametrization Representation

We have to show that $(P-Q)$ and $(P-R)$ are linearly independent with (iii) from [(Linear Independence) Show that for two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n $, the conditions (i), (ii), (iii) are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778247/linear-independence-show-that-for-two-vectors-v-w-in-mathbbrn-the-con)

Let $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda \cdot (P-Q) + \mu \cdot (P-R) = 0$ (*)

We have to show: $\lambda = \mu = 0$

Through contradiction: If $\mu \neq 0$ then $\lambda P - \lambda Q + \mu P - \mu R = 0$ according to (*)
$$\implies (\lambda + \mu)P - \lambda Q - \mu R = 0$$
If $\mu \neq 0$ then
$$\implies R = \frac{\lambda + \mu}{\mu}P - \frac{\lambda}{\mu}Q$$ that means $R$ is on a line with $P$ and $Q$ which contradicts the assumption.

So that means $\mu = 0$

Then it follows from (*) that $\lambda (P-Q) = 0$, that means $\lambda P = \lambda Q$

If $\lambda \neq 0$, then $P=Q$, that means $P,Q,R$ lie on a line, which contradicts the assumption.

So that means $\lambda = 0$

Part 3: $E$ is the only plane. Assume $E'$ is another plane, such that $E \neq E'$. Then $P,Q,R \in E \cap E'$.

$E \cap E'$ means Part 1 is a line as intersection of two planes, which contradicts the assumption.