# (Linear Independence) Show that for two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n $, the conditions (i), (ii), (iii) are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric

Show that for two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n $, the conditions below are equivalent:

(i) $v \neq 0$, and there exists no $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ with $w = \rho \cdot v$

(ii) $w \neq 0$, and there exists no $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$ with $v = \rho \cdot w$

(iii) Let $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda v + \mu w = 0$, then it follows necessarily that $\lambda = \mu = 0$

---

It's obviously about linear independence. I know what linear independence means, two or more vectors cannot span the same space. In other words, the only solution for the system $\alpha \cdot \text{vector1} + \beta \cdot \text{vector2} = 0$ is if $\alpha = \beta = 0$. This seems to be condition (iii).

Linear independence happens when one vector is not a multiple of the other vectors, so that's what conditions (i) and (ii) seem to show.

But do I need to prove that formally somehow ? It makes intuitive sense, but I'm a bit confused about what they expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) $\implies (ii)$
if $w\neq 0$ and $v=\rho w$ since $\Bbb R$ is a field exist the inverse of $\rho$ namely $\frac{1}{\rho}$ but this lead to a contradiction since $\frac{1}{\rho} \in \Bbb R, w = \frac{1}{\rho} v$ contradicting (i)

---

(ii) $\implies$ (iii) Similar to what we do before if $\lambda v + \mu w = 0$ than $v = -\frac{\mu}{\lambda}w$, absurd.

---

I think by now you get the point, now if you prove (iii) $\implies$ (i) you have proven that these three conditions are equivalent.

**Edit:** IMO proving those type of things could be trivial but are a good exercise to write simple things formally, in order to be able writing much more complicated things later!

Comment: For (iii) $\implies$  (i) : If $v  \neq 0 $ and $w = \rho \cdot v$ then this would imply $\frac{1}{\rho} \cdot w = v$. That would imply $\lambda \cdot \frac{1}{\rho} \cdot w + \mu \cdot w = 0$. That would imply $\lambda = - \rho \cdot \mu $. That would contradict the rule from (iii) that says $\lambda = \mu = 0$, so this cannot be true. Is that correct ?